# Filter cse results using labels

Tags: google-search, google-custom-search, google-search-api

I want to get the json response for the domains I already have labeled.

`var URL = "https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=**&cx=**&q=allinurl:"+queryUrl+"&fields=items(title,link,snippet)&more:"+label;`

When I use that query, my results are the same as if I don't use `more:label`

The domains in one label aren't in the rest, and the labels have the FILTER mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my own mistake, the `more` key has to go within the query (`q=`) with a +, like this:

`&start="+startResult+"&q=allinurl:"+queryUrl+"+more:"+label`